# Directive Dilemma in Angular JS with BindToController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

Im using Angular 1.5 and 'bindToController' with a directive to pass information to controller (directives controller). The issue is any data fetched from a service that needs to be passed through to the directive doesn't get bound to the directive controller and I cannot find out why.

Main Site Controller:

```
angular.module('site')
.controller('siteController', ['$scope' , '$stateParams', '$timeout', '$q', '$filter', 'authCookie', 'SiteService',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $timeout, $q, $filter, authCookie, SiteService) {

        // Set 'this'
        var ctrl = this;

        // Site
        ctrl.loadSite = function() {
            // Service
            SiteService.site.query({id:1}, function(res) {
                // Result
                ctrl.site = res.site
            });
        }
        ctrl.loadSite();
    }
]);
```

The data is fetched by the 'SiteService' and set to 'ctrl.site' this seems to work fine.

This is the directive html (passing site):

```
<sitesettings site="ctrl.site"></sitesettings>
```

The Site Directive and controller:

```
angular.module('siteSettings', []);

// =========
// Directive 
// =========

angular.module('siteSettings')
.directive('sitesettings', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:true,
        transclude: true,
        controller: 'siteSettingsController',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindToController: {
            site:'=',
        },
        templateUrl:'/modules/app/components/siteSettings/siteSettings.html',
        css:'/modules/app/components/siteSettings/siteSettings.css'
    }
})

// ==========
// Controller
// ==========

angular.module('siteSettings')
.controller('siteSettingsController', [ '$timeout', '$location', '$q', '$filter', 'authCookie', 'siteSettingsService', 'Upload',
    function( $timeout, $location, $q, $filter, authCookie, siteSettingsService, Upload) {

        // Set 'this'
        var ctrl = this;
        // Console.log returning empty string
        console.log(ctrl.site)

    }
]);
```

The above consoles an empty string (when the data is in fact populated in the site controller)The issue seems to be caused by the service, anything that is set within the service cannot be bound to the directives controller. By setting ctrl.site = 'Im a string' within the site controller and not within the service it gets bound to the directives controller.Thus highlighting the service causing the problem.

How would I go about solving this? Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome.

Update - Site Service Code:

```
angular.module('index')
.service('SiteService', ['$http', '$resource',
    function($http, $resource) {
        return {
            // Site
            site:$resource('/api/site/:id', {}, { 
                query:{ method:'GET', isArray:false, params:{ id:'@id' } },
            }),
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: your service is performing an asynchronous request, the result is just not still there when siteSettingsController is executed. Either put a $watch or store the promise in an object that you access in the siteSettingsController.

Comment: @Walfrat Thanks for your comment. So If i changed the site.query to following it should work?  SiteService.site.query({id:1}).$promise.then(function(res) { // Set Data });

Comment: If `SiteService.site` is a resource object, then it should work in both cases. What is `SiteService`?

Comment: a bit more tricky : you should store the promise : `ctrl.site=[...].$promise` and not the value. Then in your `siteSettingsController` you can do if(angular.isPromise(ctrl.site)){ctrl.site.then(function(site){ ctrl.siteValue = site})}else{ctrl.siteValue = ctrl.site;} Otherwise perform a $watch on your `ctrl.site` to detect changes from upper controller. By the way it is only if you want to console.log, if you use a template, you will see the ctrl.site once it has been fetched by the server.

Comment: @dfsq I have updated the question to show the resource. Let me know what you think.